# Corona SDK: scene pushing/popping

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I'm a bit confused with Corona scenes.

I'd like to have my main menu (which I dont want released or purged) push to a level when a button is tapped.

So far I can achieve that with `storyboard.gotoScene("level1")`

However, once level1 is done, I'd like to go back to the mainMenu scene as it were (I use a scrollview whose position I keep). I don't want to recreate mainMenu.

How exactly should I be doing this? Does gotoScene automatically release my existing mainMenu? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply go to the menu scene using `gotoScene("")`

Keeping in mind that Corona will auto purge your scenes if it feels that is is needed.

> By default, storyboard will automatically purge (e.g. remove the
>   scene's display group, while leaving the actual module in memory) the
>   least recently used scene whenever the OS receives a low memory
>   warning.
>
> If you would like to manage the purging of scenes manually and disable
>   this auto-purging functionality, you can set
>   storyboard.disableAutoPurge to true. The default value is false.

To turn off autoPurge:

```
-- turns "off" auto-purge on low memory functionality
storyboard.disableAutoPurge = true
```

This will prevent Corona from removing your scenes automatically, which means you are left in charge of this task.